# how to know AD Forest name in central admin?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm creating user profile service application in sharepoint server 2013 . for creating new sync connection , I need to enter Forest name. But I don't have permissions to see AD . I just have Farm account.

I have tried the below powershell cmd but no luck.

```
$forest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
```

So anyone have smart idea to know forest name?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Farm Account should have read access to AD for many farm purposes.
So let's suppose it has it.

You can get forest name by executing below code in PowerShell (suspect you have not loaded assembly before calling GetCurrentForest):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.DirectoryServices') | Out-Null
[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
```

If you have AD Module installed on your server, you can also use it like this:

```
Get-ADForest
```

or

```
(Get-ADDomain).Forest
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the AD DS Tools installed you can run the cmdlet [Get-ADDomainController](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852293.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
Get-ADDomainController
```

or

```
Get-ADDomainController | Select-Object Forest
```